# Считывание числа с консоли

Tags: c#, консоль, числа

Я cчитываю числа через `Read` и `ReadLine`. Возможно я не совсем корректно составил функцию `ReadToInt()`.

Возникает такая ошибка:

[image: ошибка]

```
using System;

namespace visibility
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Read\n"+ReadToInt());
            Console.WriteLine("ReadLine\n"+ReadLineToInt());
        }

        static int ReadLineToInt()
        {
            string str;
            str=Console.ReadLine();
            return Int32.Parse(str); 
        }

        static int ReadToInt()
        {
            char ch;
            int x;
            int i = 0;
            string str="";
            do
            {
                x = Console.Read();
                ch = Convert.ToChar(x);
                str += ch;
                i++;
            }
            while (x != 13);

            return Int32.Parse(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: На `str` наведите, и посмотрите чтож там за число такое. Напомню, что `int` это чисто цифры, без точек, запятых, пробелов, и чего-либо еще.

Comment: В функции ReadLineToInt() RealLine не вызывается, наверно, потому что в буфере еще что-то осталось после функции ReadToInt()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не используйте `Console.Read()`, это низкоуровневое чтение. Чтобы его использовать, надо знать много нюансов кодирования управляющих последовательностей и символов. Ну например клавиша Enter - это не 10 и не 13, а последовательность 2 символов с кодами 10 и 13 (CR+LF). То есть прочитав 10, нужно тут же выполнить чтение следующего символа, и если там 13, то это Enter. Ничего подобного в вашем коде я не нашел. Поэтому для посимвольного ввода, если очень хочется, используйте более высокоуровневый метод `Console.ReadKey()`. Пример с ним в самом низу ответа, а пока давайте без посимвольного попробуем.

Если надо вводить до тех пор, пока ввод не будет корректным, то безотказный ввод числа может выглядеть так:

```
static int ReadInt32(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

А использовать его так:

```
int result;
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        result = ReadInt32("Введите число: ");
        break;
    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Некорректный ввод: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

---

Или еще можно так без обработки исключений:

```
static bool TryReadInt32(string prompt, out int result)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    return int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);
}
```

А использовать его так:

```
int result;
while (true)
{
    if (TryReadInt32("Введите число: ", out result))
        break;
    Console.WriteLine($"Некорректный ввод числа, попробуйте еще раз");
}
```

---

И совсем альтернативный способ, который будет позволять вводить только цифры. Это к вопросу, как полностью управлять посимвольным вводом.

Данный метод поддерживает только цифры, то есть ввод только неотрицательных чисел, но для учебного примера сойдёт.

```
static int ReadIn32(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    string number = string.Empty;
    ConsoleKey key;
    do
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
        key = keyInfo.Key;

        if (key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && number.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.Write("\b \b"); // затирание последнего символа Backspace+пробел+Backspace
            number = number[0..^1]; // удаление последнего символа из строки
        }
        else if (keyInfo.KeyChar >= '0' && keyInfo.KeyChar <= '9')
        {
            Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
            number += keyInfo.KeyChar;
        }
    } while (key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
    if (number.Length == 0) // пользователь ничего не ввёл
    {
        number = "0";
        Console.Write(number);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    return int.Parse(number);
}
```

Здесь ещё нет защиты от переполнения, то есть если пользователь введёт очень большое число, которое не влезет в `Int32`, то будет исключение. Я не стал добавлять проверку, чтобы не усложнять и без того не простой код.

Comment: с силой .net 7 можно ещё классно обобщить метод `Read<T>() where T : IParsable<T>`

Comment: @iiKuzmychov верно, но для начала и этого хватит

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за детаьный ответ. Я стараюсь разбираться в тонкостях, чтобы находить оптимальный способ решения задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Может так ?

```
static int ReadLineToInt()
{
    return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Переписал функцию ReadToInt(), таким образом, обошел ошибку.

```
        static int ReadToInt()
        {
            char ch;
            int x;
            int i = 0;
            string str="";
            do
            {
                x = Console.Read();
                 ch = Convert.ToChar(x);
                if (x != 10 && x != 13) str += ch;  // добавил проверку
                i++;
            }
            while (x != 10);  // выхожу из цикла когда все закончилис все символы в буфере

            return Int32.Parse(str);
        }
```

Не уверен, что так правильно?..

Comment: Неправильно конечно же, сейчас дам ответ